# Issue with performance in using MERGE statement and UNION ALL when loading delta change TSQL

Tags: t-sql, merge, union, database-performance, union-all

Is there anyone have considered using the MERGE statement and UNION ALL tables for DML (I/D/U) in T-SQL?
It's better performance if using UNION ALL but the stored procedure is long and hard to read with me (~1k3 lines)
I want to use MERGE instead but I have no experience with it, please help me.

Comment: Honestly, you are normally just better off sticking to an Upsert, rather than a `MERGE`.

Comment: A number of very knowledgeable people have raised concerns with merge over the years, both in terms of unpredictable performance characteristics, as well as possible ACID vioilations, and other bugs. Having said that, the syntax is very appealing, and I have used it many many many times when integrating delta loads (from CDC) to other applications, via dump-to-staging-table-and-merge, such that our various systems have probably run `merge` statements hundreds of thousands of times, without ever encountering a problem with performance, or having any kind of inconsistency.